# Foundation 4:Unable to overwrite its regular expression to validate password

Tags: validation, zurb-foundation

I want to overwrite password pattern provided by foundation(zurb) but its not identifying my overwritten regular expression and generated error according to its by default expression.
By default,passwords validation  provided by foundation is "must be at least 8 characters with 1 capital letter, 1 number, and one special character".
For that I have used following:

1)

```
<head>
<script>
$(document)
  .foundation()
  .foundation('abide', {
    patterns: {
      new: ^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$,
       }
  });
 </script></head>
<body>
<form class="custom" data-abide>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <label>Password <small>required</small></label>
            <input type="password" pattern="new" required >
                <small class="error" data-error-message="">validation error.</small>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

2)

```
<form class="custom" data-abide="">
</form>
```

3)Directly used pattern in input tag:

```
<input type="password" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$" required >
```

But all these are not working.Please suggest me something to resolve my problem.

You can find the sample program - [here](http://rtest1.s3.amazonaws.com/test/sample_problem.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1381343340&Signature=8yNa1Y38357RyJJEvC0SvEVD0zc=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing pattern called `password` does the trick. Change

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

at the bottom of `index.html` to the following code:

```
<script>
  $(document)
    .foundation()
    .foundation('abide', {
      patterns: {
        password: /^\w{3,14}$/,
      }
    });
</script>
```

Note that the regex you provided (`^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$`) should be written as `/^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$/` in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried it but didnt work for me..@JackyChan's solution worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Update the value before running foundation:

```
<script>
Foundation.libs.abide.settings.patterns.password = /^\w{3,14}$/;
$(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that's worked for me - Foundation totally ignores custom patterns and I'm using Foundation 5.  I have spent hours trying everything else.  Thank you!

Comment: yup it did the trick, foundation custom patterns totally fail