# Password in a form, Foundation 5 (ZURB)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, zurb-foundation

I use foundation ([ZURB](http://foundation.zurb.com/)) here is my code:

```
      <form data-abide>
      <div class="name-field">
      <label>Your name <small>required</small></label>
      <input type="text" required >
      <small class="error">Name is required and must be a string.</small> 
      </div>
      <div class="password-field">
      <label>Password <small>required</small></label> 
      <input type="password" required>
      <small class="error">A Password is required.</small>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

In the Password part I want to replace the password with dots without testing the password, because it requires a complex password of eight as: `aaaaaAA2` 
and in my case I only simple password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding Abide during Foundation initialization, you can define your own custom patterns or override the default patterns to validate against. To use simple password,

```
   $(document)
   .foundation()
   .foundation('abide', {
    patterns: {
    password: /^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$/, 
   }
  });
```

Password must be between 4 and 8 digits long and include at least one numeric digit.
Matches 
1234 | asdf1234 | asp123
Non-Matches 
asdf | asdf12345 | password

for more http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html
http://regexlib.com/(A(13E-t-BjvZ-WvDNI3kEXWexqe-dnRabCLhUJT4HCwiq39cFxk1bCp2xTgMv4ZLuwh4z02qwn-LwirPbo_Y1NF6Tnx6zEJKJ9ukU7WXcOnRM1))/Search.aspx?k=password&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: I tried, but it gives no result.


`
..................    
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document)
     .foundation()
     .foundation('abide', {
   patterns: {
   password: /^(?=.*\d).{4,9}$/, 
     }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
`

Comment: i gave the example just read foundation abide link and regex link.. and then try your own

Comment: I moved the code into the HEAD, but I got another error :) Off-canvas menus not working

Comment: This should work according to the docs but didn't in my case (v5).The only solution that worked was [setting the value before initializing Foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20327015/805003).

Comment: I think this solution works only for Foundation (V < 5).. @onemanarmy solution worked for me